# How to return the answer of a bluetooth command with response

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I have a class that has several methods to communicate with a bluetooth device.
For example

```
getVersion()
getBatteryLevel()
```

In those commands, I use

```
connectedDevice!.writeValue(data as Data, for: rxCharacteristic,type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
```

Now the response will trigger the delegate method `didUpdateValue`.

But I would like to use my methods like this:

```
var batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel()
```

How can I get the answer, that comes via `didUpdateValue` in my method, so that I can `return` it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic [asynchronous programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)) problem.

Literally, this means that your function (for example `getBatteryLevel()`) must wait until your computer has received the response from the remote device.

The Swift programming language supports asynchronous programming under the term [concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/).

Comment: Would it be a solution, to collect messages in a buffer until a timeout. Then inside the methods, iterate through that buffer to find the batteryLevel message?

Comment: @Risto In its current form, this answer is really just a glorified comment. Showing an example of how to implement the code would go a long way toward making this a useful answer.